Doxygen use different layout for *.c and *.h files
A customer wants us to provide a full calling API for a library: public functions and the structures used in those public functions.  But the customer also wants to know what static data is stored in each module.  Standard Doxygen output for *.h files meets the requests. But for *.c files, I only want to output the static data variables and their structs.
I have tried modifying the DoxygenLayout.xml to limit *.c files to just structures and variables. This works fine. But, I don't know a way to apply this restricted DoxygenLayout.xml for *.c files and a non-restricted layout for *.h files.
I started looking at the domxmlparser python scripts that Doxygen supplies, which should provide a path to parse *.c and *.h differently.  But, before I go down that route, I want to know if I'm missing something obvious.

What's the question?

The question is if it is possible to apply one file layout from DoxygenLayout.xml to *.c files and a different file layout to *.h files.

Please edit your question to clarify that (assume that no one reads the comments).

Which version of doxygen are you using? Does the customer want to have the extra information in the same document or could it be another document. i.e. run doxygen twice. I don't think theer is an out of the box solution with the layout file so you will have to create something yourself
